# Typescript cannot determine type after 2nd generic indexing

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm trying to write a function that will take an API string and a method and figure out its request and response types. Here's my attempt so far.

```
interface APIDef {
    '/api/api1': { 
        GET: {
            request: {
                api1getparam1: string,
                api1getparam2: number,
            },
            response: {
                api1getres1: string[],
                api1getres2: number[],
            }
        },
        POST: {
            request: {
                api1postparam1: string,
                api1postparam2: number,
            },
            response: {
                api1postres1: string[],
                api1postres2: number[],
            }
        },
    },
    '/api/api2': { 
        GET: {
            request: {
                api2getparam1: boolean,
                api2getparam2: number,
            },
            response: {
                api2getres1: string[],
                api2getres2: number[],
            }
        },
        POST: {
            request: {
                api2postparam1: boolean
            },
            response: {
                api2postres1: 'success',
            }
        },
    },
}

async function callAPI<A extends keyof APIDef, M extends APIDef[A]>(api: A, method: M, request: APIDef[A][M]['request']): Promise<APIDef[A][M]['response']> {
    return await (await fetch(api, {
        method: method,
        body: JSON.stringify(request)
    })).json() as ReturnType<typeof callAPI<A, M>>;
}
```

But it seems like typescript has trouble figuring out the type for `APIDef[A][M]`, although I do not see any reason why it cannot. This seems to be a [known issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/21760). As a workaround, I tried the following, where method is a fixed union type:

```
interface APIDef {
    '/api/api1': { 
        GET: {
            request: {
                api1getparam1: string,
                api1getparam2: number,
            },
            response: {
                api1getres1: string[],
                api1getres2: number[],
            }
        },
        POST: {
            request: {
                api1postparam1: string,
                api1postparam2: number,
            },
            response: {
                api1postres1: string[],
                api1postres2: number[],
            }
        },
        PUT: never,
        PATCH: never,
        DELETE: never,
        HEAD: never,
    },
    '/api/api2': { 
        GET: {
            request: {
                api2getparam1: boolean,
                api2getparam2: number,
            },
            response: {
                api2getres1: string[],
                api2getres2: number[],
            }
        },
        POST: {
            request: {
                api2postparam1: boolean
            },
            response: {
                api2postres1: 'success',
            }
        },
        PUT: never,
        PATCH: never,
        DELETE: never,
        HEAD: never,
    },
}


type Method = 'GET' | 'POST' | 'PUT' | 'PATCH' | 'DELETE' | 'HEAD';

async function callAPI<A extends keyof APIDef, M extends Method>(api: A, method: M, request: APIDef[A][M]['request']): Promise<APIDef[A][M]['response']> {
    return await (await fetch(api, {
        method: method,
        body: JSON.stringify(request)
    })).json() as ReturnType<typeof callAPI<A, M>>;
}
```

This works, but requires all APIs to have all methods even if they're not used. How can I re-write the generic code so that I can get away without having to include all methods in all APIs?

Answer (score 0):

In such situation I write this kind of check:

```js
K extends keyof T ? T[K] : never;
```

Since this is done in a function parameter position, you are assured that the user input will be rejected if the value isn't found because the type will be `never`.

All you need to do is write a recursive utility type that repeats the check for each property access.

```js
type Get<Path extends string[], T> =
    Path extends [] ? T
    : Path[0] extends keyof T
        ? Get<Path extends [string, ...infer R extends string[]] ? R : [], T[Path[0]]>
        : never
```

```js
async function callAPI<A extends keyof APIDef, M extends string & keyof APIDef[A]>(
  api: A,
  method: M,
  request: Get<[A, M, "request"], APIDef>
): Promise<Get<[A, M, "response"], APIDef>> {
  const requestObject = ["GET", "HEAD"].includes(method)
    ? { method: method }
    : {
        method: method,
        body: JSON.stringify(request)
      };

  return fetch(api, requestObject)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .catch(console.error);
}

const ok = callAPI(
  "/api/api1",
  "GET",
  { api1getparam1: "foo", api1getparam2: 1 }
);
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.9.4#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-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)

I took the liberty to change your implementation because you were simply turning off type checking, but you do you.